# TweetDeck is "unable to connect" to Twitter

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I've been using and old version of TweetDeck for ages, and just noticed that Twitter has taken over TweetDeck.

So I installed the latest version.  When I try to login, I get the following error message:

> Unable to connect.  Please check your network.

The old TweetDeck continues to work perfectly.

Why am I getting this message with the new TweetDeck?

Comment: is it giving any other information which could help us for debugging your issue .

Comment: That is all I am getting once I have typed in my username ans password.

Comment: but we need info ,whats actually causing the problem . we need some info .

Comment: Well, after installing TweetDeck, I try to login, and I get the above error message.  It is as simple as that.  I don't know where to get more info from.  The old TweetDeck works perfectly.  I have updated flash, and air, and reinstalled TweetDeck, and I get the same problem.

Comment: For more info on troubleshooting the new TweetDeck: https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169869#

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not missing much. The new Twitterfied Tweetdeck is almost comically bad. I'd recommend either sticking with 0.38.2 (the last Adobe AIR version) or finding a new client.

Comment: How is this the answer?

Answer (score 7):

It's horrible, but this is the solution :

1. Close Tweetdeck
2. Open Internet Explorer
3. Go to https://api.tweetdeck.com
4. Close IE
5. Start Tweetdeck
6. Log on.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you, I don't see why the other answer was accepted when it isn't really a solution to the problem, just a suggestion.

Comment: See [this blog](http://tidusuper91.altervista.org/blog/2012/09/12/tweetdeck-risolvere-lerrore-unable-to-connect-please-check-your-network/) for some background on why there's a problem and how the solution works (The page is mainly in Italian, but look at the blue box with a reply from Twitter Support which is in English).

Comment: IE works for me, Chrome still gets the error.  What a gong show.